# Press and hold button iOS

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6

I'm a newbie to IOS development, and have a bit of java and Arduino programming experience. I am working on a simple morse code project. How can I keep track the amount of time a button is pressed in iOS? Would I just have to have a big loop which keeps scanning for the button being pressed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIButton long press with finger stationary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389923/uibutton-long-press-with-finger-stationary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

Add a property to your class to store the date of the latest touch down. Preferably in a class extension in the `.m`-file.

```
@interface YourViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *buttonTouchDownDate;
@end
```

Connect your button, programmatically or with interface builder, to the `Touch Down` and `Touch Up Inside` control events. This is described in great detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389923/uibutton-long-press-with-finger-stationary).

Then store the date when the button was touched down. When the finger is lifted, calculate the time interval between the stored date and now.

```
- (IBAction)buttonDidTouchDown:(id)sender
{
    self.buttonTouchDownDate = [NSDate date];
}
- (IBAction)buttonDidTouchUp:(id)sender
{
    // Will return a negative value, so we use the ABS-macro.
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = ABS([self.buttonTouchDownDate timeIntervalSinceNow]); 
    NSLog(@"Time interval: %f", timeInterval);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine 2 functions results:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

there you get the start time.

And

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  if (self.touchInside) {
    NSLog(@"TouchUpInside");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"TouchUpOutside");
  }
}
```

if if a touchupinside than you get the "endtime" and calculate the duration.